# Conditional linear regression with indicator variables (Python)

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, python, categorical-encoding, indicator-function

I have the sample dataset below 20 observations of Y variables and 20 observations of X variables. Both are normalized (z-scored).

I have a prior that (i) larger magnitude X values with $abs(X) >= 1$ (larger in either direction) will lead to response Y variable of the opposite sign and (ii) smaller magnitude X values tend to predict Y values of the same direction

There are three regressions that I can think of to model this and each of them show different results empirically (see below), please help:

1. $Y_{\left| x\right|>=1}=const_{a1} + \beta_{a1} X_{\left| x\right|>=1} + \epsilon_{a1} \hskip 1em \text{and}\hskip 1em Y_{\left| x\right|<1}=const_{a2} + \beta_{a2} X_{\left| x\right|<1} + \epsilon_{a2}$
2. $Y=const_b + \beta_1 X_{\left| x\right|>=1}+\beta_2 X_{\left| x\right|<1}+\epsilon_b$
3. $Y=const_c + \beta_1 X_{\left| x\right|>=1}+\beta_2 X_{\left| x\right|<1}+\beta_3 X+\epsilon_c$

My questions are:

1. Empirically, the results are slightly different in all cases, but they seem conceptually related. Which approach is best? It seems (2) + (3) imply that both share the same intercept whereas the same is not true in (1), but when is each case conceptually better?
2. What is the desired way to optimize for the threshold in which I set the magnitude cutoff (in this example it is just 1)?

I noticed the $R^2$ adjusted and the const coefficients/tstats are the same across (2) vs (3), but the coefficients for $X_{big}$ and $X_{small}$ are different. Which is better to use? My intuition is (2) is best because the regressors are uncorrelated by construction. Including the original regressor in (3) yields multicollinearity in the regression

````py
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([ 
    [ -0.168,  0.008 ],
    [ 0.528,   -0.437 ],
    [ 0.326,   -0.288 ],
    [ -1.942,  -0.35 ],
    [ -1.026,  -0.651 ],
    [ -0.098,   2.021 ],
    [ 0.006,   -0.283 ],
    [ 1.37,    0.906 ],
    [ 0.326,   -0.083 ],
    [ -0.494,  -0.571 ],
    [ 0.082,   0.231 ],
    [ -0.224,  0.24 ],
    [ 1.071,   -1.954 ],
    [ -1.909,  -0.229 ],
    [ 1.093,   0.874 ],
    [ 0.155,   -2.035 ],
    [ -1.076,  1.541 ],
    [ 1.508,   -0.191 ],
    [ 0.277,   1.25 ],
    [ 1.432,   -0.023 ],   
], columns=["Y", "X"])

# Baseline regression Y = BX + e
X = sm.add_constant(df[["X"]])
y = df["Y"]
mod = sm.OLS(y, X)
res = mod.fit()
print(res.params, res.rsquared_adj, res.tvalues)
#const    0.061827 (tstat = 0.269005)
#X       -0.019145 (tstat = -0.081188)
#R^2 Adj -0.055169160198053735

##############################################
## Case 1 - Two separate regressions
##############################################
# one with abs(X) >= 1 and another with abs(X) < 1 against Y
X_big = sm.add_constant(df[df.X.abs()>=1][["X"]])
X_small = sm.add_constant(df[df.X.abs()<1][["X"]])
y_big = df[df.X.abs()>=1]["Y"]
y_small = df[df.X.abs()<1]["Y"]
mod_big = sm.OLS(y_big, X_big)
mod_small = sm.OLS(y_small, X_small)
res_big = mod_big.fit()
res_small = mod_small.fit()
print(res_big.params, res_big.rsquared_adj, res_big.tvalues)
#const    0.107063 (tstat = 0.349238)
#X       -0.250686 (tstat = -1.461938)
#R^2 Adj  0.22137506933425555
print(res_small.params, res_small.rsquared_adj, res_small.tvalues)
#const    0.129043 (tstat = 0.510604)
#X        1.213269 (tstat = 2.153536)
#R^2 Adj  0.20624642685897143

##############################################
## Case 2 - Single regression: Y = X_big + X_small + e
##############################################
df["X_big"] = (df["X"].abs()>=1) * df["X"]
df["X_small"] = (df["X"].abs()<1) * df["X"]
X = sm.add_constant(df[["X_big","X_small"]])
y = df["Y"]
mod = sm.OLS(y, X)
res = mod.fit()
print(res.params, res.rsquared_adj, res.tvalues)
#const      0.123517 (tstat = 0.611966)
#X_big     -0.251533 (tstat = -1.120672)
#X_small    1.211718 (tstat = 2.334740)
#R^2 Adj    0.19765694552458224

##############################################
## Case 3 - Single regression: Y = X + X_big + X_small + e
##############################################
X = sm.add_constant(df[["X", "X_big","X_small"]])
y = df["Y"]
mod = sm.OLS(y, X)
res = mod.fit()
print(res.params, res.rsquared_adj, res.tvalues)
#const      0.123517 (tstat = 0.611966)
#X          0.320062 (tstat = 1.701229)
#X_big     -0.571595 (tstat = -2.492749)
#X_small    0.891656 (tstat = 2.516228)
#R^2 Adj    0.19765694552458224
```
````

Comment: Unless I am mistaken model 3 is not even identified. Could you post significance results coefficients X,X_small , X_big?

Comment: Model 3 is at the bottom. I also added t-stats.